# Is there any way to allow user to execute commands for 2 days only

Tags: sudo

How to give a sudo command permission for a specific time? is there any way to give rights to perform a specific command for 2 days only in sudoers file.?

Answer (score 19):

The sudoers file does not support time based restriction but there is an easy method. Create a file with your alterations in `/etc/sudoers.d/` (with `sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/yourfile`):

Add to a file (example: `file.sh`) the following

```
mv /etc/sudoers.d/yourfile /etc/sudoers.d/.yourfile
```

And this will disable your alterations:

```
 sudo at -f file.sh 2pm + 2 days
```

Example:

```
at -f file.sh 2pm + 2 days
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 4 at Thu Oct 15 14:00:00 2015
```

In this case it would move the file over at 2 pm 2 days after you  issue the command. The `at` [manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man1/at.1posix.html) has some options (you can use a time, days, weeks, months, years, keywords like next or add/subtract periodes). Have some tests with the option to make sure you understand it (Something to consider: it matters if you start the `at` before or after 2pm on the day itself.)

`at` also survives reboots so is a good tool to use for these kind of things. 
And you can toggle access ...

```
sudo mv /etc/sudoers.d/.yourfile /etc/sudoers.d/yourfile | at 2pm + 2 days
sudo mv /etc/sudoers.d/yourfile /etc/sudoers.d/.yourfile | at 2pm + 4 days
sudo mv /etc/sudoers.d/.yourfile /etc/sudoers.d/yourfile | at 2pm + 6 days
sudo mv /etc/sudoers.d/yourfile /etc/sudoers.d/.yourfile | at 2pm + 8 days
```

and make that user go nuts (wtf now I can do this).

The README in `/etc/sudoers/`:

```
# As of Debian version 1.7.2p1-1, the default /etc/sudoers file created on
# installation of the package now includes the directive:
# 
#   #includedir /etc/sudoers.d
# 
# This will cause sudo to read and parse any files in the /etc/sudoers.d 
# directory that do not end in '~' or contain a '.' character.
# 
# Note that there must be at least one file in the sudoers.d directory (this
# one will do), and all files in this directory should be mode 0440.
# 
# Note also, that because sudoers contents can vary widely, no attempt is 
# made to add this directive to existing sudoers files on upgrade.  Feel free
# to add the above directive to the end of your /etc/sudoers file to enable 
# this functionality for existing installations if you wish!
#
# Finally, please note that using the visudo command is the recommended way
# to update sudoers content, since it protects against many failure modes.
# See the man page for visudo for more information.
```

If I read this correctly it will not execute any file with a "." anywhere in the name. So the 1st `mv` command I placed the "." in front making it also invisible. If correctly assumed you can place a "." anywhere. Careful with the "~", that one is used as a "backup" feature by editors like gEdit.

---

`at` is not installed by default. To install

```
sudo apt-get install at
```

Comment: Thanx, i already thought of it but the situation is multiple users using the file for their own purpose so its not possible to backup and restore sudoers file every time bcoz other users are also modifying the same sudoers file so when i restore old file all the changes made by ohter users will be gone...

Comment: How about this sir? Oh and might I suggest to your multiple users to also themself to use the sudoers.d with their own filename. Seems a lot better than editing sudoers.

Comment: @AbbasKapasi create a new file in `/etc/sudoers.d` that won't be used by your other users.

Comment: I think the command used all throughout the answer should have been `mv`, not `cp`.

Comment: where do you see cp? *whistles innocently*

Comment: `In this case it would copy the file over at 2 pm 2 days after you issue the command.` whoops

Comment: I am horribly confused. How does piping the output of a command through `at` prevent the command from running until the specified time? In my tests, the command runs immediately, and the `at` command has nothing to run (which is what I expect). Surely it needs to be more like this: `echo 'sudo mv /etc/sudoers.d/yourfile /etc/sudoers.d/.yourfile' | at 2pm + 2 days` ? What have I misunderstood?

Comment: Nothing @PaddyLandau I used the wrong version. Now with example.